# numerical expression has x elements: only the first used

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to break up a for-loop into a tibble then use the `summarize()` function to get the final value.

This is the loop

```
prob <- NULL
for(i in(4:16)){
  p1 = dbinom(i,16,0.2)
  k=13-i
  p2=sum(dbinom(k:30,30,0.2))
  prob = c(prob,p1*p2)
  print(i)
}
```

I got this far

```
df <- tibble( i=4:16) %>% 
  mutate(p1=dbinom(i,16,0.2),k=as.integer(13-i)) %>% 
  mutate(p2=sum(dbinom(k:30,30,0.2)))
df
```

this produces the following error

```
Warning message:
In k:30 : numerical expression has 13 elements: only the first used
```

The warning says the k only has 13 elements, but this should not be a problem because the rest of my data has 13 elements. I am not sure how to fix the problem.

Comment: The root issue is because you can't do a sequence from multiple values  - e.g.: `c(1,2,3):3` gives the same *warning*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should manipulate data by row: try this

```
tibble( i=4:16) %>% 
     mutate(p1=dbinom(i,16,0.2),k=as.integer(13-i)) %>% 
     rowwise() %>%
     mutate(p2=sum(dbinom(k:30,30,0.2)))
```